# How to give Permission two users for a share folder. One can read, write, delete and other can read write but not delete

Tags: 16.04, server, samba, users

1. share folder name All
2. Two user: user1 and user2
3. Both of share same folder and user1 can read,write,delete but user2- read,write remove permit to delete.

[image]

```
getent passwd jahid3--
jahid3:x:1001:100:for delete:/ALL8:/bin/sh

getent passwd jahid4--
jahid4:x:1002:100:Not for delete:/ALL8:/bin/sh


[jahid@all7 ~]
cut -d: -f1,3-4; ls -ld
drwxrwxr-t 5 jahid3 sambashare 4096 Dec 22 22:16 .
```

Comment: "delete" permission is affected by the parent directory's permission. Are these users in the same group?

Comment: I can create two different group. but can they share same share folder two different rule. Same work i create in windows 2012 server. but in linux i can't

Comment: Please Edit https://askubuntu.com/posts/1103808/edit your post, and show us the results of these commands: `(getent passwd user1;getent passwd user2) | cut -d: -f1,3-4; ls -ld All`

Comment: When you say "write" for user2, do you mean edit existing files, or create new files? I don't think you'll be able to allow a user to create a file but not remove a file.

Comment: @glenn jackman ##   "Yes not remove or delete file"

Comment: @waltinator -- ## plz see – user1845453 8 mins ago

Comment: Writing a file by removing all lines is basically deleting the contents of a file. You can not prevent that unless you create a directorywatcher that makes copies of that file as it changes.